# How to add information to a specific column in a pre-existing database

Tags: php, mysql, database, lamp

I have a database named `week1` which includes columns: `age, address, voternum, voterhistory, status, gender, precinct, county, and zip5`.

The information for all rows excluding `voterhistory` is already in the table!

I need to import the `voterhistory` column separately from a *text file* named *vhist* into the table where `voternum` of the week1 table is equal to `voternum` of the *vhist* text file.

Multiple lines from the text file can be put into the `voterhistory` column and should be separated by a comma.

For example:

Within week1 there is a person with `voternum = 1234`.
In the *vhist* text file there are 3 records where `voternum = 1234`.

One has a `voterhistory = 2011`, one has a `voterhistory = 2012`, and one has a `voterhistory = 2013`.

This means when importing the *vhist* text file those 3 records should import into the `voterhistory` column of the week1 table like so:  `2011, 2012, 2013`.

Sorry if this sounds confusing, but it's the only way I know how to explain it.  If you need further information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL we have a function called [CONCAT_WS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) It basically concatenates string values using a specified separator. Take a look at the link.

I would use a temp table to load vhist into memory.Then join table week1 to the temp table vhistory and update week1 based on the key matches. That gets you out of having to implement conditional logic in your SQL join.

In code it will look something like this, you may have to work on this a bit to get it to run:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE vhistory  (
     voternum VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    , voterhistory VARCHAR(10)
   );

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/vhist.txt' INTO TABLE vhistory;


UPDATE week1 SET voterhistory=SELECT CONCAT_WS(SELECT ',',voterhistory FROM vhistory
WHERE week1-voternum = vhistory-voternum );
```

I did not run this code as I don't have your data.

Comment: It seems there is an error in the last segment when I try to update week1. Any ideas as to what it could be?     "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT CONCAT_WS(SELECT ',',voterhistory FROM vhistory
WHERE week1-voternum = vhistory-voternum );' at line 1"

Comment: I don't have your schema or table layouts as such you will have to work on this code a bit to get it to work for you. It represents a solid start. You may need to create a second temp table to store your concatenated result and then join that to week1